# Given a periphery of island mark its interior in matrix (Algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, matrix, graph-algorithm

We are given a matrix of size N which is completely filled with 0's and we are also given a list of coordinates which contains the coordinates of the periphery of an island. Now we have to mark the island (periphery + area that is part of the island) as 1's.

I am having trouble coming up with a solution to this problem, I thought of bfs/dfs but can't think of a way to implement this.
(Please assume that there is 1 island only and the input is correct i.e. all input coordinates form a closed shape and are valid

```
N = 5
coordinates = 
0,2
1,1
1,3
2,0
2,4
3,1
3,3
4,2
```

So this is what output should look like ---

```
    0 1 2 3 4
  0 0 0 1 0 0
  1 0 1 1 1 0 
  2 1 1 1 1 1 
  3 0 1 1 1 0 
  4 0 0 1 0 0
```

All the coordinates marked and the square boxes inside them marked which are a part of the island.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that peripheral coordinates are just ends of filled horizontal lines.

In this case use for-loop to set elements inside lines to 1. Pseudocode:

```
lastrow = -1
lastcol = -1  
for every line:
   extract row, col
   if row = lastrow:
       for (i=lastcol + 1; i<=col; i++):   //fill line
          A[row][i] = 1
       lastrow = -1    // to treat possible space in the line
   else:
       A[row][col] = 1     //set the only cell
   lastrow = row
   lastcol = col
```

Comment: It seems to me that the question is unclear a little bit about what looks like the input data. It might be needed to perform this kind of operation on every line, then on every column, then even possibly on every line ...

Comment: @Damien Perhaps you are right, but I don't see such necessity for data presented at this moment

Answer (score 0):

If you know a point that is inside the island, then you can solve this with a DFS or BFS-based flood fill starting at that point.

It's a little bit tricky to find such a point reliably, though, so I suggest an easier way: Instead of using a flood fill to find the points that are inside the island, start the flood fill at all the 0 points along the matrix boundary to find the points that are *not* inside the island.  Then set all the points you *didn't* find to 1.